# Ordenar diccionario en python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Quiero ordenar este diccionario (valores) según el valor de la key en orden ascendente. Vea abajo:

```
valores{5:20000, 3:10000, 4:15000}
```

Así que el diccionario final se vería así.

```
valores{3:10000, 4:15000, 5:20000}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependiendo de la versión de Python que uses la solución puede variar:

- **En Python >= 3.7 tenemos garantizado que los diccionarios mantienen el orden de inserción**. Este cambio de implementación se realizó en realidad en Python 3.6, pero en esta versión se consideraba aún un efecto colateral de la implementación y por tanto susceptible de cambiar sin previo aviso. A partir de Python 3.7, no obstante, pasó a considerarse una característica del lenguaje.

  Por lo tanto solo tenemos que crear un nuevo diccionario a partir de las parejas clave/valor ordenas convenientemente, lo cual podemos conseguir con [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

  ```
  valores = {5:20000, 3:10000, 4:15000} 
  valores_ord = dict(sorted(valores.items()))

  # También usando diccionarios por compresión
  valores_ord = {k: v for k, v in sorted(valores.items())}
  ```
- **En versiones anteriores de Python a la 3.7, la implementación de los diccionarios hace que no tengan orden interno** por lo que el orden de inserción no se mantiene. Esto causa que en cada iteración sobre los mismos o sus vistas podamos obtener resultados diferentes en cuanto al orden. La solución es usar [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.OrderedDict), subclase de `dict` pero que mantiene el orden de inserción y añade algunos métodos relacionados con esta característica:

  ```
  import collections


  valores_ord = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(valores.items()))
  ```

> En cualquier caso recordar que el orden es en función de cuando se
>   inserta la clave, por lo que si agregamos nuevas claves necesitaremos
>   volver a ordenar.

---

### Extra

- Si queremos invertir el orden basta con usar el argumento reverse de `sorted`:

  ```
  valores = {5: 20000, 3: 10000, 4:1 5000} 
  valores_ord = dict(sorted(valores.items(), reverse=True))
  print(valores_ord)  # {5: 20000, 4: 15000, 3: 10000}
  ```
- Si queremos ordenar por el valor y no por la clave, basta con usar el argumento `key` de `sorted`:

  ```
  import operator

  valores = {5: 20000, 3: 90000, 4: 15000} 
  valores_ord = dict(sorted(valores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
  print(valores_ord)  # {4: 15000, 5: 20000, 3: 90000}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que los diccionarios en Python no tienen orden y los valores no se van a mostrar siempre en el mismo. Para solucionarlo puedes usar "OrderedDict" que te recuerda el orden en el que fueron introducidos. A continuación te dejo un enlace con un ejemplo de uso:

https://codeday.me/es/qa/20181128/353.html

Si lo que quieres es ordenarlo como más te interese sin preocuparte de si lo añades en orden o no, entonces primero debes pasar los valores a una lista. Te dejo otro enlace con un ejemplo para que le eches un vistazo:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-es/2004-October/005961.html